# All svg change their color to red when I use a specific svg in my code

Tags: html, css, angularjs, svg

I've got some SVG icons, which I use in my web app. They all have specific colors. Regardless of the color, all SVG icons have one color, instead of one, which has two colors (gray and red).

I have an angular component to set my icons in my web app. The directive of my component looks like this:

```
import {constants} from '../../../index.constants';

export class MyIcon{
    public icon: string;
    public iconsPath: string = constants.PATH_TO_ICONS;
    public fileExtension: string = '.svg';

    static options: ng.IComponentOptions = {
        template: '<div ng-include="ctrl.iconsPath + ctrl.icon + ctrl.fileExtension"></div>',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        controller: MyIcon,
        bindings: {
            icon: '@'
        }
    };
}
```

I can use my component in my code and with a binding named icon, I can set the name of the icon I'd like to use:

```
<my-icon icon="pencil"></my-icon>
```

In the attachment you can find the icon with the two colors. When I use this in my component, the colors of all other icons turn to red and their shape changes.

When I remove the faulty icon, all other icons have their specific color and look like they have to look. I have no idea why this happens, perhaps because the faulty icon has two colors?

I noticed, that the red of the faulty icon is the same like the red from all other icons, when they change their color.

**Example:** Icons from my navigation with their specific colors and without the faulty icon in my code:

[image]

**Example with error:** The icons in my navigation and all other icons in my web app look like this (red and ugly shape), when I use the faulty icon in my code:

[image]

**FAULTY SVG ICON:**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 15.62 15.62"><defs><style>.cls-1,.cls-4{fill:none;stroke-miterlimit:10;}.cls-1{stroke:#e30613;stroke-width:2px;}.cls-2{fill:#fff;}.cls-3{fill:#8b8c8d;}.cls-4{stroke:#fff;}</style></defs><title>Asset 7</title><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1"><circle class="cls-1" cx="7.5" cy="8.12" r="6.5"/><polygon class="cls-2" points="1.9 10.19 11.38 0.71 14.91 4.24 5.43 13.72 0.72 14.9 1.9 10.19"/><path class="cls-3" d="M11.38,1.41l2.83,2.83-9,9-3.77.94.94-3.77,9-9m0-1.41L1.45,9.93,0,15.59l5.66-1.41,9.93-9.93L11.38,0Z"/><polygon class="cls-3" points="0.03 15.59 3.43 14.74 0.88 12.19 0.03 15.59"/><rect class="cls-3" x="1.51" y="4.09" width="14.04" height="6" transform="translate(-2.51 8.11) rotate(-45)"/><line class="cls-4" x1="9.96" y1="1.41" x2="14.21" y2="5.66"/><line class="cls-1" x1="2.9" y1="3.52" x2="12.1" y2="12.72"/></g></g></svg>
```

**OTHER SVG:**

```
<svg id="iArrowIcon" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 7.06 12.71"><defs><style>#iArrowIcon .cls-1{fill:none;stroke-miterlimit:10;fill-rule:evenodd;}</style></defs><title>arrow</title><path id="_Compound_Path_" data-name="&lt;Compound Path&gt;" class="cls-1" d="M4904.11,1058.78l6,6-6,6" transform="translate(-4903.76 -1058.42)"/></svg>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide code of other svg please ?

Comment: @CyrilBeeckman Yes, of course - I edited my question :)

Comment: don't forget to validate this response if this solve your problem ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your svg's have same class and the svg that is causing problem is overriding css properties defined in other svgs.

What you can do is, add a parent class or id to the faulty icon, and use it to separate it's css from others.

Something like this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>SVG ICONS</title>
</head>
<body>
 
<svg id="iStopIcon" class="iStopIcon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 15.62 15.62"><defs><style>
#iStopIcon .cls-1,#iStopIcon .cls-4{fill:none;stroke-miterlimit:10}#iStopIcon .cls-1{stroke:#e30613;stroke-width:2px}.cls-2{fill:#fff}.cls-3{fill:#8b8c8d}.cls-4{stroke:#fff} 
 </style></defs><title>Asset 7</title><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1"><circle class="cls-1" cx="7.5" cy="8.12" r="6.5"/><polygon class="cls-2" points="1.9 10.19 11.38 0.71 14.91 4.24 5.43 13.72 0.72 14.9 1.9 10.19"/><path class="cls-3" d="M11.38,1.41l2.83,2.83-9,9-3.77.94.94-3.77,9-9m0-1.41L1.45,9.93,0,15.59l5.66-1.41,9.93-9.93L11.38,0Z"/><polygon class="cls-3" points="0.03 15.59 3.43 14.74 0.88 12.19 0.03 15.59"/><rect class="cls-3" x="1.51" y="4.09" width="14.04" height="6" transform="translate(-2.51 8.11) rotate(-45)"/><line class="cls-4" x1="9.96" y1="1.41" x2="14.21" y2="5.66"/><line class="cls-1" x1="2.9" y1="3.52" x2="12.1" y2="12.72"/></g></g></svg>
 
<svg id="iArrowIcon" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 7.06 12.71"><defs><style>
 #iArrowIcon .cls-1, .cls-4{fill:#ccc;stroke-miterlimit:10;fill-rule:evenodd;}</style></defs><title>arrow</title><path id="_Compound_Path_" data-name="&lt;Compound Path&gt;" class="cls-1" d="M4904.11,1058.78l6,6-6,6" transform="translate(-4903.76 -1058.42)"/></svg> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here I am using Id, you can use class instead if you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

Your svg use their own style and take the same class.

When you load the last icon, css of this icon rewrite rule of color for other on the class `.cls-1`

Try to modify your svg with other class or fill the 1 color svg via css like this :

```
.myIcon{
    fill: grey;
}
```

Comment: Works also thanks. I used the solution from azs06. Cheers